# AlamoFire no thread warning

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, alamofire

while using AlamoFire to make a request and access UI element on the completion block I don't get any warnings, however, if I tried doing the same thing without AlamoFire I get "UILabel.text must be used from main thread only", I wonder what's happening here?

AlamoFire Example

```
    makeRequest(parameters:parameters,URL:.request){
    validatedResponse in 
       label.text = "anything"
    }
           private func makeRequest(parameters:[String:Any]?,URL:URLs,requestType:requestType,method:HTTPMethod , completion: @escaping (_ response:APIResponse) -> ())
        {
            APIinterface.afManager.request(
                baseUrl + URL.rawValue,
                method: method,
                parameters: parameters
                )
                .validate()
                .validate(contentType: ["application/json"])

                .responseJSON
                {
                    response in
                    debugPrint(response)

                    guard let validatedResponse = self.validateResponseForAPI(response: response) else { return }
                    //let validatedResponse = (requestType == .api) ?
                    //    : self.validateExternalResponse(response: response)

                    completion(validatedResponse)

            }
        }
```

Native Example

```
 makeRequest(parameters:parameters,URL:.request){
    validatedResponse in 
       label.text = "anything"
    }

          private func makeRequest(parameters:[String:Any]?,url:URLs,requestType:requestType,method:HTTPMethod , completion: @escaping (_ response:ResponseObject?) -> ())
    {
        guard let url = URL(string:baseUrl + url.rawValue) else
        {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

        // set up the session
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        // make the request
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
        {
            (data, response, error) in
            // do stuff with response, data & error here
            print(response)
            print(error)
            completion(self.validateResponseForAPISwift4(response: data))
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Do you understand what the warning means? Have you used the debugger on both sets of code and noticed the difference in the thread used to run your completion handler that updates the label?

Comment: Yea I know what this warning means, my question was why does Alamofire call the handler on the main thread while URLSession data task doesn't. 
I think every case must have a good reason explains why they do it like that.
 I always use Alamofire callback and never noticed any delay in UI drawing or any problem, that's why I'm asking!

Comment: You should update your question with what you stated in your comment. That makes your question much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specify otherwise, Alamofire callbacks are always executed on the main thread.  That is why you are not getting the warning when using Alamofire.